# Plotly Express 3D vectors

Tags: python, express, vector, 3d, plotly

In python I am busy calculating the closest point of approach between two aircraft for which I have radar point coordinates AND the speed vectors.

To test the algorithm, I am setting up some standard positions and speed vectors and calculate the closest point of approach.
To study the result, I want to create in Plotly Express:

the two starting **points**

the two speed vectors of the aircraft, each represented by an **arrow** from their starting point.

a **line** between the two paths at the location of the closest point of approach. The two points could each be (probably) on the extended line of the initial speed vectors.

Why Plotly Express? Because you can move and swivel around them to investigate.
I had it working in Matplotlib, but then I cannot move around them to study the interaction in 3D.